# Variable assignment in remote server using shell command through Ruby script is not working

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have to run shell command through ruby script in multiple server where as the ruby script will be doing SSH into server and then running that. I am able to run the script till variable assignment into remote machine and then gives me wrong results because the variable assignment at line 15 is not working. Below is the code:

```
1:require 'open3'
2:require 'net/ssh'
3:require 'fileutils'

4:HOME_PATH = "/road/street/home/"
5:HOME_TAR_FILE = "#{HOME_PATH}/dinner.tar.gz"
6:HOME_REPO = "/road/xyz/abc/dinner.tar.gz"
7:HOME_SOFT = "#{HOME_PATH}home-latest"

8:def home_build_processing(server,user)
9:  Net::SSH.start(server, user) do |ssh|
10:    ssh.exec!("scp server123:#{HOME_REPO} #{HOME_PATH}")
11:    puts "************** Download Completed ****************"
12:    ssh.exec!("tar -C #{HOME_PATH} -xvzf #{HOME_TAR_FILE}")
13:    ssh.exec!("rm -rf #{HOME_TAR_FILE}")
14:    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; home_latest=$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1)") 
15:    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; home_version=$(echo $home_latest'_'$(date +%Y-%m-%d))")
16:    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; mv $home_latest $home_version")
17:    puts "************** Processing Symlink**********************"
18:    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; ln -sfnv $home_version #{HOME_SOFT}")
19:  end
20: end


home_build_processing(server1,user1)
home_build_processing(server2,user2)
```

Error: line 15 home_latest is not having any value

Answer (score 0):

because every exec is a session. The previous variable is already gone.
You can send the command as a chain using &&

```
"cd #{HOME_PATH}; home_latest=$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1) && home_version=$(echo $home_latest'...
```

reference: [net-ssh](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Session.html#M000093)

Answer (score 0):

From net-ssh source code:

> `exec!` same as exec, except this will block until the command finishes. Also,
>   if no block is given, this will return all output (stdout and stderr)
>   as a single string.
>   `matches = ssh.exec!("grep something /some/files")`
>   the returned string has an exitstatus method to query it's exit satus

Try something like this

```rb
def home_build_processing(server, user)
  Net::SSH.start(server, user) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!("scp server123:#{HOME_REPO} #{HOME_PATH}")
    puts "************** Download Completed ****************"
    ssh.exec!("tar -C #{HOME_PATH} -xvzf #{HOME_TAR_FILE}")
    ssh.exec!("rm -rf #{HOME_TAR_FILE}")
    home_latest = ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; echo $(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1)")
    home_version = ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; echo #{home_latest}'_'$(date +%Y-%m-%d)")
    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; mv #{home_latest} #{home_version}")
    puts "************** Processing Symlink**********************"
    ssh.exec!("cd #{HOME_PATH}; ln -sfnv #{home_version} #{HOME_SOFT}")
  end
end
```